# HTTP client returns random errors on timeout

Tags: http, go, go-http

I have an HTTP client with a custom `RoundTripper` which in turn uses the `http.DefaultTransport` to handle the request.
Now imagine I have a slow server which takes a long time to respond and it makes my http client timeout and cancel the client. Here is the code for the client:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type rt struct {
    roundTripper func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

func (r rt) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return r.roundTripper(req)
}

func main() {

    c := http.Client{
        Timeout:   3 * time.Second,
        Transport:  rt{RoundTripper(http.DefaultTransport)},
    }
    resp, err := c.Get("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
    } else {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println(string(body), err)
    }

}
func RoundTripper(next http.RoundTripper) func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
        resp, err := next.RoundTrip(req)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("err: %w", err)
        }
        return resp, nil
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the error I'm receiving on timeout is randomly one of `net/http: request canceled` or `context deadline exceeded`.
Now I know they should be semantically the same thing but I'm failing to understand why it's returning each and when?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/2hamed/b87b8ba83f9e70e952d19bd4e2839bcf) is the server code if you want to try it for yourself.

Comment: Can you shed light on what you try to do with all this roundtripping?

Comment: @Volker The actual `RoundTripper` in my code is for circuit-breaking, retrying, and some other domain-specific tasks. But it's all irrelevant. This happens inside the `http.Client`.

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting `context deadline exceeded`, since you aren't passing a context to your request. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, this is. You can try to run this exact code and see for yourself.

Comment: @Flimzy it may happen because selects are not deterministic and the request context is manipulated here
`net/http/client.setRequestCancel(req *Request, rt RoundTripper, deadline time.Time) (stopTimer func(), didTimeout func() bool)`
and the deadline argument you see comes from the `client.Timeout` field, which is used as a base when the timeout of the context is more than that one.

Answer (score 2):

The function **net/http/client.setRequestCancel()** is used to set the cancel of the request. There are three ways

- The second will return: **net/http: request canceled**
- The third will return: **context deadline exceeded**

Because both use the same deadline, **time.now()+client.Timeout**.
So according to the runtime schedule, the request will be cancelled randomly through these two methods.

```
    https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transport.go#L2652

    case <-cancelChan:
        // return err: net/http: request
        pc.t.CancelRequest(req.Request) canceled
        cancelChan = nil
    case <-ctxDoneChan:
        // return err:
        pc.t.cancelRequest(req.Request, req.Context().Err())
        cancelChan = nil
        ctxDoneChan = nil
```